# How can we add a payment registration in zen cart?

Tags: zen-cart

How can we add a payment registration in zen cart?
right now the registration for zen cart is free, I would like to implement a payment module for that. Anyone know about such a plug in?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though your describing "membership" type functionality. Zen Cart doesn't have this and any plugins that I know of for it.

There are several possible ways to implement it, but all would really be a hacks and which is appropriate would depend on how you want it to work, so more detail would be needed from you before this could be answered.